# Split function isn't recognising white space from text copied from internet page source

Tags: vba, split

I've set up a function to process data copied and special pasted (value only) onto my worksheet.
The data in question is a name "John A Smith"

And my method is

```
Dim vFullName As Variant
Let vFullName = Split(sName, " ")
```

When I split the pasted string, I only get 2 arrays; [0] John & [1] A Smith
If I enter the data myself I get the expected 3 arrays; [0] John, [1] A & [2] Smith

I can't understand why the pasted string isn't splitting completely. Can anyone tell me why the second space isn't being registered.
The Spaces are physically there.

Cheers

Comment: is this actually VBA? or is it VB?

Comment: Using Excel 2007, and always presumed it was VBA

Comment: Just not seen the `Let` keyword used in VBA for a few years... no worries. In answer to your question - have you checked that the secondd whitespace character is actually a space `Chr(32)` and not something else?

Comment: Yeah, trying to be 'proper' with my programming language as I learn thus using Let :)

Comment: I'm guessing it may not be chr(32) but not sure what else it could be?

Comment: @Ben - I would drop the `Let`: it may be "proper" but really no-one uses it  ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this first:

```
Sub CheckWhitespace(strCheck As String)
    For i = 1 To Len(strCheck)
        If Not Mid(strCheck, i, 1) Like "[a-zA-Z]" Then Debug.Print "Chr value of whitespace (pos " & i & "): ";Asc(Mid(strCheck, i, 1))
    Next
End Sub
```

Then see what the `Chr` value is, once you know you can use the `Replace()` function to convert it to a space and then split that string instead, for example:

```
strArray = Split(Replace(sName, Chr(10), Chr(32)), Chr(32))
```

Comment: Turns out to be character 160 which is a non-breaking space. Guessing the internet site is combining strings creating this character. I appreciate the insight into this and for helping me identify the problem. Thank you.

Comment: HTML will ignore multiple spaces `Chr(32)` when it is 'compiled' and so the developer needs to use `&nbsp;` or Non Breaking Back Space to display these correctly on a webpage. You may or may not have already known that, but thought I would add as a comment to clarify for any future readers as I imagine this is a common issue with copying web data.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assuming that it is a whitespace, split it using the character between the two words. Meaning, copy the character and paste it into your split function.

Comment: I like your thought process, might be useful for getting around this and any future problems like this. Thank you.